# javascript how to set double appendChlid function

Tags: javascript

I try to lern and to transform an HTML CODE(normal code) to javascript unter using the appendChild function atm and i dont understand how it works if i want to create appended parts for an div DOM which is in an div DOM included, because i want to write functions for many many papers ^_^ which i dont want to set it by hand. the problem is, if i try to use the same code under for the other images doesnt take the CSS formats that the images doesnt change it from img1 to img2 to img3 if i klick the right parts. The normal HTML format works fine. any ideas would be cool. thx

What i did: Will see it in the code under //(A). If i try to use it together it doesnt work, and also if i try (A) alone

```
//--Thats the (normal code) which i want to transform to javascript
<div class="container">
  <input type="radio" name="images" id="i1" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="images" id="i2" >
  <input type="radio" name="images" id="i3" >
  <div class="slide_img" id="one">
    <img class="img" src="bilder/UE_1_2018.PNG">
    <label for="i3" class="pre"></label>
    <label for="i2" class="nxt"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="slide_img" id="two">
    <img class="img" src="bilder/UE_2_2018.PNG">
    <label for="i1" class="pre"></label>
    <label for="i3" class="nxt"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="slide_img" id="three">
    <img class="img" src="bilder/UE_3_2018.PNG">
    <label for="i2" class="pre"></label>
    <label for="i1" class="nxt"></label>
  </div>
</div>

//DIV where the javascript code would be included
<div class="container">
  <div id="y2018"></div>
</div>

//Thats my first try to transform it before i write the for functions
<script>
  function inputradios(year, divName) {
    //---MAIN-ELEMENT---
    var element1 = document.getElementById(divName);
    //---INPUT---
    var para1 = document.createElement("input");
    para1.type = "radio";
    para1.name = 'images';
    para1.setAttribute('checked','checked');
    para1.setAttribute("id", "i1");
    element1.appendChild(para1);
    //---DIV---
    var para1_1 = document.createElement("div");
    para1_1.setAttribute('class','slide_img');
    para1_1.setAttribute("id", "one"); 
    element1.appendChild(para1_1);
    //---IMG---
    var element2 = document.getElementById(para1_1);
    var para1_1_1 = document.createElement("img");
    para1_1_1.setAttribute('class','img');
    para1_1_1.setAttribute('src','bilder/UE_1' + '_' + year + '.PNG');
    element1.appendChild(para1_1_1);
    //(A) element2.appendChild(para1_1_1);
    //---lABEL 1---
    var para1_1_2 = document.createElement("label");
    para1_1_2.setAttribute('class','pre');
    para1_1_2.setAttribute('for', 'i1' );
    element1.appendChild(para1_1_2);
    //(A) element2.appendChild(para1_1_2);
    //---lABEL 2---
    var para1_1_3 = document.createElement("label");
    para1_1_3.setAttribute('class','nxt');
    para1_1_3.setAttribute('for', 'i1' );
    element1.appendChild(para1_1_3);
    //(A) element2.appendChild(para1_1_3);

    //SAME CODE WITH SOME DIFFERENT CHANGES TO IMPLEMENT IMAGE2,3,...

  }
  //inputradios(year, NrOfPages, divName);
  inputradios(2018, 'y2018');
</script>
```

Comment: btw its probably not need to use .setAttribute : you cna just do object.property=value

Comment: `var element2 = document.getElementById(para1_1);` para1_1 is not an id

Comment: @jonathanHeindl oh damn jeah. many thx. i didnt see it. you solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//---IMG---
var element2 = document.getElementById('one');
element1.appendChild(para1_1_1);
//(A) 
element2.appendChild(para1_1_1);
```

Works like a charm :) many thx

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code a bit to make it more clear and consolidated.

If you're working with DOM functions, keep with using `setAttribute` rather than doing `element.id='whatever';`, it'll save you frustration later on.

In this example I use loops to create brevity instead of creating basically the same thing over and over.

In the second loop you'll see some nonsense with `? :` like `(i===0) ? 'one' : (i===1) ? 'two' : 'three'`.  If you are unfamiliar these are [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) which can be used to shortcut if/else blocks.

```
function inputradios(year, id) {
  // I changed divName to id, for clarification an id is not a name
  const parentDiv = document.getElementById(id);

  // Create INPUTS
  // <input type="radio" name="images" id="i1" checked>
  // <input type="radio" name="images" id="i2" >
  // <input type="radio" name="images" id="i3" >
  for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
    const input = document.createElement('input');
          input.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
          input.setAttribute('name', 'images');
          input.setAttribute('id', 'i'+ (i+1));
    if (i===0) {
      input.setAttribute('checked','checked');
    }
    parentDiv.appendChild(input);
  }
  // Create the DIVs
  // <div class="slide_img" id="one">
  //   <img class="img" src="bilder/UE_1_2018.PNG">
  //   <label for="i3" class="pre"></label>
  //   <label for="i2" class="nxt"></label>
  // </div>
  // <div class="slide_img" id="two">
  //   <img class="img" src="bilder/UE_2_2018.PNG">
  //   <label for="i1" class="pre"></label>
  //   <label for="i3" class="nxt"></label>
  // </div>
  // <div class="slide_img" id="three">
  //   <img class="img" src="bilder/UE_3_2018.PNG">
  //   <label for="i2" class="pre"></label>
  //   <label for="i1" class="nxt"></label>
  // </div>
  for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
          div.setAttribute('id', (i===0) ? 'one' : (i===1) ? 'two' : 'three');
          div.setAttribute('class', 'slide_img');
    const img = document.createElement('img');
          img.setAttribute('class', 'img');
          img.setAttribute('src', 'bilder/UE_'+ (i+1) +'_2018.PNG');
    const labelPre = document.createElement('label');
          labelPre.setAttribute('for', 'i'+ ((i==0) ? 3 : (i-1)));
          labelPre.setAttribute('class', 'pre');
    const labelNxt = document.createElement('lable');
          labelNxt.setAttribute('for', 'i'+ ((i===2) ? 1 : (i+1)));
          labelNxt.setAttribute('class', 'nxt');
    div.appendChild(img);
    div.appendChild(labelPre);
    div.appendChild(labelNxt);
    parentDiv.appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

Comment: hi. i try that also to modify the code to an smoother form. thx to you, to see an different form but your code has some fails in the <code> labelPre.setAttribute('for', 'i'+ ((i===0) ? 3 : (i-1))); or in the div.setAttribute('id', (i===0) ? 'one' : (i===1) ? 'two' : i===2) ? 'three');</code> part, because it doesnt change between all pics, but thats a problem for tomorrow for me :) i tried to change that one, two ... to an list, but if i try <code>var element2 = document.getElementById(list[i]);</code> with an <code>var list = ["one", "two", "three"]</code> it doesnt works and i dont know why

Comment: You can't use <code> in replies, you can use backticks.  The best way to debug your issue is to run the code, then right click the element and select "inspect" or "inspect element", this will open up the debugger.  You will be able to see the rendered HTML in the DOM.